# Factory pattern from generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have generic interface `IProcessor<T, TU>` and 2 implementations of it:

`StandartDocumentProcessor` and `ModDocuemntProcessor`.

I'm going to use Factory pattern (or smth similiar) to instantiate variable *currentProcessor*.

`IProcessor<T, TU> currentProcessor = Factory.Create(argument)`.

Then I'm going to call method `currentProcessor.ProcessFrom()` and `currentProcessor.ProcessTo()`.

*1st problem*: it's impossible to have `IProcessor<T,TU>` or `IProcessor` types for currentProcessor, as CLR doesn't allow this and insists to have specific type for my variable.

*2nd problem*: I surfed over the internet and found ugly solutions with *Reflection* or `Activator.CreateInstance()` which have familiar issues with downgrading performance.

Please advice, is it possible to avoid: reflection, casting to `object` or using `dynamic`.

**UPD**: `IProcessor.cs`

```
public interface IProcessor<T, TU> where T : DocumentValidation
    {
        HtmlContent RetrieveDocument(SearchItem item);

        bool ValidateObject(T obj);

        T ProcessFrom(HtmlContent content);

        TU ProcessTo(T source);

        bool SaveTo(TU target, T source);

    }
```

First implementation of `IProcessor` - `StandardDocumentProcessor.cs`

```
class StandardDocumentProcessor : IProcessor<Document, XmlDocument>
    {
        public HtmlContent RetrieveDocument(SearchItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool ValidateObject(Document obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public Document ProcessFrom(HtmlContent content)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public XmlDocument ProcessTo(Document source)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool SaveTo(XmlDocument target, Document source)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Second implementation of `IProcessor` - `ModDocumentProcessor.cs`

```
public class ModDocumentProcessor : IProcessor<ModDocument, XmlDocument>
    {
        public HtmlContent RetrieveDocument(SearchItem item)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool ValidateObject(ModDocument obj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ModDocument ProcessFrom(HtmlContent content)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public XmlDocument ProcessTo(ModDocument source)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool SaveTo(XmlDocument target, ModDocument source)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

and now I'm going to create factory pattern to instantiate `IProcessor<T, TU>` with some specific class.

```
????? currentProcessor = Factory.Create(input_argument_which_allows_to_define_concrete_implementation_of_IProcessor)
```

*That's no matter to display realization of `Create` method here. I'm kindly asking about just **returning type of `Create` method**.*

Comment: It sounds like maybe you should declare a non-generic base interface, `IProcessor`. It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just describing bits of the code.

Comment: Can you explain how `IProcessor<T, TU>` and `IProcessor` interfaces are related?

Comment: Unless you're doing this 100,000 times in a loop the performance hit from reflection will be unmeasurable.

Comment: to Fabio: `IProcessor` doesn't exist. I mean, it would be nice to have common `IProcessor` type to call the same methods from different implementations.

Comment: Is problem in factory? where you need use reflection or Activator?

Comment: to Fabio: exactly. Problem in factory or more precisely - in returning type of method `Factory.Create()`

Comment: Jon Skeet: how to create base interface `IProcessor`, having inner methods with generic types?

Comment: Move generic type argument from interface declaration to method declaration `bool Validate<T>(T value)`. Then you will be able return only one type with generics methods

Comment: Fabio: good idea. Applying it in my code...

Comment: to Fabio: unfortunately no. Method declaration doesn't allow to implement `bool Validate<T>(T value)` from interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `C# 4.0` you can simple declare your factory method as dynamic and it will work:

```
public static dynamic Create(string at) {
   if (condition)
     return new StandardDocumentProcessor();
   else
     return new ModDocumentProcessor();
}
```

Invocation:

```
dynamic m = Create("mod");
```

Of course, this is like cheating because by using `dynamic` you'll loose type safety (risking runtime exceptions) and it'll decrease performance.

If have no idea about your app domain, but if this aspect is import for you, I would change some things and try generic `out` parameters.

```
public interface IProcessor<out T, out TU> where T : DocumentValidation {
    HtmlContent RetrieveDocument(SearchItem item);
    bool ValidateObject(DocumentValidation obj);
    T ProcessFrom(HtmlContent content);
    TU ProcessTo(DocumentValidation source);
}
```

Factory:

```
public static IProcessor<DocumentValidation, ProcessResult> Create(string at) {
  if (condition(at))
    return new StandardDocumentProcessor();
  else
    return new ModDocumentProcessor();
  }
```

Note that I removed the `SaveTo` method because it does not fit into this pattern. Move it to another interface if you require it anyway. `ProcessResult` is a base class / interface for `XmlDocument`.

Just another note: everything would be simpler if you wouldn't use generics at all and work with inheritance / base classes. *The factory pattern is commonly used to **hide and encapsulate implementation details** and types, including some generic parameters.* If you want to get type information out of your factory, perhaps it isn't the best idea to use a factory.

Comment: Thanks, ventiseis. Actually, the `dynamic` keyword is the thing I'd like to avoid, but the second part of your answer is very useful. Now I see, that inheritance of my `DocumentProcessor` classes is failed. I have to create base `Document` class instead of `DocumentValidation` and then use `IProcessor<>` correctly. Couldn't fully agree with your last statement about definition of factory pattern - it's more about defining exact type instead of hide implementation details, but I wouldn't like to mix all this questions in one thread.